# How can I tell Robot Framework to normalize escaped spaces in paths?

Tags: path, escaping, robotframework

I want to use a path like `~/Library/Application\ Support/` and join it with the proper folder and filename. According to Robot documentation, `Join Path` Keyword is supposed to normalize the result. Yet the result of the join still has the backslash escaped space, which its other keyword `File Should Exist` can't resolve properly.

So who is doing things wrong, `Join Path`, `File Should Exist`, or me?

```py
def get_os_application_support_path():
    return '~/Library/Application\ Support/'
```

and

```
Database Path
    ${OS_PATH}=             Get Os Application Support Path
    Run Keyword And Return  Join Path    ${OS_PATH}    'Database.db'
```

will return `'~/Library/Application\ Support/Database.db'` even though I expect `'~/Library/Application Support/Database.db'`

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] that illustrates the problem you are having?

Comment: sure, it's added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

normalize uses os.path.normpath which eliminates double slashes, but not your escaped backslash.

In the following example the escaped space only exists in the robot file.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Handle Spaces
    ${path}=  Join Path  ~/Library/Application\ Support  Foo.txt
    Log To Console  ${path}
    File Should Exist  ${path}
```

Note that `Log To Console` doesn't have escaped spaces.

```
==============================================================================
Path                                                                          
==============================================================================
Handle Spaces
C:\Users\eddy.pronk\Library\Application Support\Foo.txt
| PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Path                                                                  | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\work\output.xml
Log:     C:\work\log.html
Report:  C:\work\report.html
```

Tested with Python 2.7.14 and robotframework 3.0.4

Comment: I forgot to mention that I get the Path as a string variable from python. so it's `'~/Library/Application\ Support/'`. My quickfix was to change the source to provide unescaped string, but I still wonder why normalize didn't catch that.

Comment: @tuexss normalize uses `os.path.normpath` which eliminates double slashes, but not your escaped backslash. On Linux a backslash is a valid character in a filename. You can create a directory called `Application\ Support`. You can of course use `p.replace('\ ', ' ')` in your function.